# How do you import apache commons lang in java?

Tags: java

I tried importing the imports on the apache commons lang website, but they don't seem to work. It keeps telling me the last two packages im trying to import in the code below do not exist. I'm using Java on Netbeans 8.2, what seems to be the problem?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Object;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang ;


public class Howmanysentences {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter: ");
        String shortEssay = input.nextLine();



        int counterr = StringUtils.countOccurrencesOf(shortEssay,".");

        System.out.println(counterr);


    }

}
```

Comment: Did you add them to your build path? They aren't included with plain old Java SDK.

Comment: Do they exist in your project/classpath/etc? You can't import random classes without actually having them present.

Comment: In addition to @ItamarGreen 's linked question, you may want to spend some time researching the likes of Maven and Gradle, which are popular tools to automate getting and adding dependency jars in builds.

Comment: @DaveNewton how do i know?